# Fb messenger: quick_replies gets invalid data error

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot

I'm getting this error:

```
   { message: '(#100) Invalid data',
     type: 'OAuthException',
     code: 100,
     error_subcode: 2018032,
     fbtrace_id: 'H3qnFWWxE9u' } }
```

when posting this to Facebook messenger:

```
    var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: message.title,
      quick_replies:[
        {
          content_type: "text",
          title: "Button",
          payload: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Weird part is, Facebook renders my quick replies & buttons.
But I'm logging a 100 error.
I'm not getting the same issues with other Facebook message types,
e.g. structured data / cards.

What causes this?
How can I fix/circumvent this?

Comment: Your message data is OK. I'm sure. Please check `message.title`, make sure it not NULL

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the JSON above is correct. The issue was elsewhere. Fb seems to throw this invalid data error message when something else goes wrong, not just with the data posted.